# pivotwide function in r

Tags: r, pivot, identifier, survey

This is data from NHANES prescription drug data:

```
SEQN RXDUSE RXDDRGID RXDCOUNT
1  93703     No                NA
2  93704     No                NA
3  93705    Yes   d03740        3
4  93705    Yes   d04532        3
5  93705    Yes   d00325        3
6  93706     No                NA
7  93707     No                NA
8  93708    Yes   d00689        3
9  93708    Yes   d03821        3
10 93708    Yes   d00746        3
```

I am trying to have it in this format:

```
seqn rxduse rxdcount rxddrgid_1 rxddrgid_2 rxddrgid_3 rxddrgid_4
93703 1 2 d00262 d04113 . .
93705 1 4 d00262 d04538 d00746 d03182
```

I tried this:

```
staxpiv <- stax2 %>%
  group_by(SEQN) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = RXDDRGID,
              names_from  = RXDUSE,
              names_prefix = 'id_')
```

And this was the output:

```
    SEQN RXDCOUNT    id id_No id_Yes id_Refused `id_Don't know`
   <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <fct> <fct>  <fct>      <fct>          
 1 93703       NA     1 ""    NA     NA         NA             
 2 93704       NA     1 ""    NA     NA         NA             
 3 93705        3     1 NA    d03740 NA         NA             
 4 93705        3     2 NA    d04532 NA         NA             
 5 93705        3     3 NA    d00325 NA         NA
```

I still have some SEQN numbers appearing twice, not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your `stax2` dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You got close. A quick point - you won't get the output example values that you gave from your input sample data, but based on your example input data here is a way to do it. NOTE that this assumes the values in RXDCOUNT are the total RXDUSE per SEQN:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Sample data
stax2 <- read.table(text = "SEQN RXDUSE RXDDRGID RXDCOUNT
93703     No       NA       NA
93704     No       NA       NA
93705    Yes   d03740        3
93705    Yes   d04532        3
93705    Yes   d00325        3
93706     No       NA       NA
93707     No       NA       NA
93708    Yes   d00689        3
93708    Yes   d03821        3
93708    Yes   d00746        3", header = T)

staxpiv <- stax2 %>%
  filter(RXDUSE == "Yes") %>%
  group_by(SEQN) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = RXDDRGID,
              names_from  = id,
              names_prefix = "rxddrgid_")

staxpiv
# # A tibble: 2 × 6
# # Groups:   SEQN [2]
#    SEQN RXDUSE RXDCOUNT rxddrgid_1 rxddrgid_2 rxddrgid_3
#   <int>  <chr>    <int>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
# 1 93705    Yes        3     d03740     d04532     d00325    
# 2 93708    Yes        3     d00689     d03821     d00746
```